# Creating multiple dataframes out of one based on string search in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, split

I am relatively new to R. I have a dataframe that has more than 10 million rows that contain 500,000 PMIDs (a type of ID). However, the code I use to run on it can only handle 4000-5000 PMIDs at most. Here is a sample of what the raw dataframe (it's all in one column) looks like:

`PMID- 28524368
OT - cardiomyopathy
OT - encephalitis
LID - 10.1111/jmp.12273 [doi]
PL - Denmark
PMID- 28523858
OT - Pan troglodytes
PST - aheadofprint
LID - 10.1111/echo.13561 [doi]
STAT- Publisher
FAU - Ruivo, Catarina
PMID- 52528302
CI - (c) 2017, Wiley Periodicals, Inc.
DA - 20170518
OWN - NLM
PMID- 18325287
STAT- Publisher
OWN - NLM
DA - 20170519
LA - eng
PMID- 95625132
FAU - Oumerzouk, Jawad
JID - 0135232
PL - Australia
PMID- 47628853
LA - eng
STAT- Publisher
AID - 10.1111/jmp.12273 [doi]`

As you can see in the example dataframe, there are only 6 PMIDs. So for the sake of the example, let's say I need to make multiple dataframes and each dataframe should only have 2 PMIDs (in my actual code I will probably do around 4000 PMIDs). Thus, I would like to split up my dataframe into 3 different dataframes that look like this (start at one PMID and end before the third PMID comes)

df1:

`PMID- 28524368
OT - cardiomyopathy
OT - encephalitis
LID - 10.1111/jmp.12273 [doi]
PL - Denmark
PMID- 28523858
OT - Pan troglodytes
PST - aheadofprint
LID - 10.1111/echo.13561 [doi]
STAT- Publisher
FAU - Ruivo, Catarina`

df2: 

`PMID- 52528302
CI - (c) 2017, Wiley Periodicals, Inc.
DA - 20170518
OWN - NLM
PMID- 18325287
STAT- Publisher
OWN - NLM
DA - 20170519
LA - eng`

df3:

`PMID- 95625132
FAU - Oumerzouk, Jawad
JID - 0135232
PL - Australia
PMID- 47628853
LA - eng
STAT- Publisher
AID - 10.1111/jmp.12273 [doi]`

Note that the row differences between each PMID is different, so it must be done by string matching PMID. I don't know how to do this on such a large dataset (how do I not manually create the dataframes? for loop?)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you proposing to split into the smaller DFs, regardless of how to find the PMID?

Comment: that's what I need help on as well...I don't want to manually create `df1 <- original[1:10, ]` etc

Comment: I was thinking maybe finding the index of each PMID and somehow subsetting to create multiple dataframes from the 1st to the 4000th, 4001th to the 8000th, etc...if anything, I guess manually creating 100-200 dataframes isn't the worst thing that could happen...I just don't know how to find the PMIDs at even intervals to begin with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so although the solution of `@thelatemail` seemed very promising, it did not work on my dataset. even after I tried the code on a smaller subset of only 1 million rows, it would constantly freeze my computer and I would have to continuously re-start my computer and re-load all the code and large file. perhaps it works better on numerical data or maybe on fewer data or maybe using `data.table` or `dplyr` or maybe I was just coding it wrong...not sure exactly why I wasn't able to implement it correctly (I would've experimented more, but I want to go home soon hah), but I was able to come up with my own solution:

```
# shows indices of each PMID
a <- which(grepl("^PMID", df$V1))
a <- as.data.frame(a)

# creates dataframes based on indices from `a` at every 4000 PMID
df1 <- original[c(a[1, 1]:a[4000, 1]), ]
df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)

df2 <- original[c(a[4001, 1]:a[8000, 1]), ]
df2 <- as.data.frame(df2)
```

etc...until df100, ha. very tedious, but I couldn't come up of a way to not do this manually...perhaps creating a function? regardless, my code ran within seconds, so I'm not complaining. plus the tedious work was just mindless work anyway that actually only took 10-15 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Make a little counter whenever you hit the start of a new group, then split. Here's a simplified example:

```
x <- rep(1:3,5)
grpsize <- 2
split(x, (cumsum(x==1)+grpsize-1) %/% grpsize)
#$`1`
#[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3
#
#$`2`
#[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3
#
#$`3`
#[1] 1 2 3
```

On your full data then you could use `grepl` to identify the start of each group:

```
split(df, (cumsum(grepl("^PMID",df$var)) + grpsize - 1) %/% grpsize)
```

Arguably you could add the counter as a new column on your dataset and use it as an identifier to go from a long to a wide dataset.

Comment: lol after running that script my R froze my computer so I had to restart it. I think I will need to manually split the 10 million rows into maybe 1 million each and then use your code (which is also splitting l o l) on each million...my example dataframe is simplified; there are about 20 rows that follow each PMID and I also hate that my R can't handle 10 million rows. will keep you updated, but I see a lot of potential in your code!

Comment: @sweetmusicality - if you are working with sizeable data then it might be worth looking at data.table or dplyr. You can use the counter above `(cumsum(... grpsize` as a 'group/group by' to do the manipulation a lot quicker.

Comment: hmm. I'll look into that as well. thank you! right now my R is running `grepl("^PMID", df)` so that I can manually split up the 10 million rows into ten dataframes of 1 million rows based on PMIDs whose indices are near each million (my R is still running...is my code right?)

Comment: @sweetmusicality - `grepl("^PMID", df$var)` - you need to reference a `var` in there somewhere - whatever your column containing all the text is called inside `df`

Comment: if the `df` is only one column, does it matter?

Comment: @sweetmusicality - yep, if `df` is actually a `data.frame` - check `class(df)` - then you have to reference the variable, not the whole object. It should be a matter of seconds, not minutes to do `grepl` - I just ran the code in <1 sec on 10M records.

Comment: oh wow, yeah, you're right! thank you!! the above code gives me `FALSE` or `TRUE` for every single 10 million indices...how do I only see which indices are `TRUE`? (I'm very inefficient and would probably use a for loop)